# BigQuery: Validate that all dates are formatted as yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Google BIGQUERY, I need to check that the values in a column called birth_day_col are the correct and desired date format: YYYY-MM-DD. The values in this column are defined as STRING. Also the values in this column are currently of the following format: YYYY-MM-DD.

I researched a lot on the internet and found an interesting workaround. The following query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT birth_day_col
    FROM `project.dataset.datatable`
    WHERE birth_day_col LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]'
    AND country_code = 'country1'
```

But the result is: "This query returned no results."

I then checked with NOT, using the following code:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT birth_day_col
    FROM `project.dataset.datatable`
    WHERE NOT(birth_day_col LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]')
    AND country_code = 'country1'
```

Surprisingly it gave all the values in birth_dat_col, which I have verified and are of the correct date format, but this result coud very much be a coincidence.

And it is very strange (wrong) that I used a query that should result only the wrong format dates, but it actually gives me the correct ones. Everything about these two queries seems like an inversation of each one's role.

The expected result of any query for this business case is to make a count of all incorrect formatted dates (even if currently this is 0).

Thank you for your help!

Robert

Comment: Your query is using forward slashes `/` instead of dashes `-` as date component separators. ISO 8601 uses dashes, not slashes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did not mentioned it. Thought it was not relevant. I already tried to use ```-``` instad of ```/``` but I get the same results. Same when using ```.``` instead ```/```.

Comment: Have you tried using `REGEX_CONTAINS` instead of `LIKE`?

Comment: When I use the ```NOT``` function it almost looks that it circumvents the ```LIKE``` function alltogether, and instead does a standard ```SELECT```, checking only for ```WHERE country_code = 'country1'```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things here:

1. Read the documentation for [the LIKE operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators) if you want to understand how to use it. It looks like you're trying to use regular expression syntax, but the LIKE operator does not take a regular expression as input.
2. The standard format for BigQuery's dates is YYYY-MM-DD, so you can just try casting and see if the result is a valid date, e.g.:

```
SELECT SAFE_CAST(birth_day_col AS DATE) AS birth_day_col
FROM `project`.dataset.table
```

This will return null for any values that don't have the correct format. If you want to find all of the ones that don't have the correct format, you can use `SAFE_CAST` inside a filter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT birth_day_col AS invalid_date
FROM `project`.dataset.table
WHERE SAFE_CAST(birth_day_col AS DATE) IS NULL
```

The result of this query will be all of the date strings that don't use YYYY-MM-DD format. If you want to check for slashes instead, you can use `REGEXP_CONTAINS`, e.g. try this:

```
SELECT
  date,
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(date, r'^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}$')
FROM (
  SELECT '2019/05/10' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-05-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT '05/10/2019'
)
```

If you want to find all dates with *either* YYYY-MM-DD format or YYYY/MM/DD format, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT date
FROM `project`.dataset.table
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(date, r'^[0-9]{4}[/\-][0-9]{2}[/\-][0-9]{2}$')
```

For example:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT date
FROM (
  SELECT '2019/05/10' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-05-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT '05/10/2019'
)
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(date, r'^[0-9]{4}[/\-][0-9]{2}[/\-][0-9]{2}$')
```

Comment: Yes, I found references online to SAFE_CAST. I just did not understand if using it will give me 100% the correct result.

Comment: Would SAFE_CAST ... AS DATE check if the date is correct also? For example, as @Dai said below: What if you have 2019/02/30? It would be interesting if this checked for this too. Please advise. Thank you! :)

Comment: `CAST` and `SAFE_CAST` require that the string has the format YYYY-MM-DD. It can't have slashes. I added another example...it's not really clear what you want to do still, but hopefully this is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another example for BigQuery Standrad SQL - with use of SAFE.PARSE_DATE

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1980/08/10' AS birth_day_col UNION ALL
  SELECT '1980-08-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT '08/10/1980'
)
SELECT birth_day_col
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', birth_day_col) IS NULL
```

with result of list of all dates which are not formatted as yyyy-mm-dd

```
Row birth_day_col    
1   1980/08/10   
2   08/10/1980
```

Answer (score 1):

[Google BigQuery's `LIKE` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators) does not support matching digits nor does it uses the `[` character in its syntax (I don't think ISO standard SQL does either - `LIKE` is nowhere near as powerful as Regex).

> `X [NOT] LIKE Y`
>
> Checks if the `STRING` in the first operand X matches a pattern specified by the second operand `Y`. Expressions can contain these characters:
>
> - A percent sign "%" matches any number of characters or bytes
> - An underscore "_" matches a single character or byte
> - You can escape "\", "_", or "%" using two backslashes. For example, "\%". If you are using raw strings, only a single backslash is required. For example, r"\%".

You should use `REGEX_CONTAINS` instead.

I note that string format tests won't tell you if a date is valid or not, however. Consider that `2019-02-31` has a valid date format, but an invalid date value. I suggest using a datatype conversion function (to convert the `STRING` to a `DATE` value) instead.